# call to member function on non object

Tags: php, function

Can someone help a beginner? 
It says that Call to a member function set() on a non-object; I have been tinkering with this for 3 days and am unable to figure out what is causing this error.

here is the code

```
function torrent_download($item_details, $output_type = 'show_torrent')
    {
    $template->set('session', $session);
$torrent = $show->torrent_download($session->value('user_id'));
    {
    if ($session->value('is_seller'))
    {
        $show_tips = $db->count_rows('users', "WHERE user_id='" . $session->value('user_id') . "' AND notif_a=0");

        if ($show_tips)
        {
            $msg_member_tips = '<p class="errormessage">' . MSG_MEMBER_TIPS_A . '<br>' . MSG_MEMBER_TIPS_B . '</p>';
            $db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "users SET notif_a=1 WHERE user_id='" . $session->value('user_id') . "'");
        }
        $template->set('msg_member_tips', $msg_member_tips);
    }



if (isset($_REQUEST['form_download_proceed']))
    {
        $download_result = download_redirect($_REQUEST['winner_id'], $session->value('user_id'));

        if ($download_result['redirect'])
        {
            header('Location: ' . $download_result['url']);
        }

        $template->set('msg_changes_saved', '<p align="center">' . $download_result['display'] . '</p>');

    }
    }
    }
```

Comment: You don't show what $template is.

Comment: Where the `$template` comes from?

Comment: $template should be something like $template = new TemplateClass(); (loading the file/snipplet first containing the class code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're getting this error inside the `torrent_download` function?

If so, that's because `$template` is undefined. Perhaps you defined it in the global script, but functions don't inherit that.

You can prevent this issue by adding: `global $template` (and any other variable from the outside you need) to the start of your function.

Answer (score 0):

This generally means your calling something on a variable that's null. What line number is the error returning??

You should add checks after your assignments to ensure the follow are not null:

```
$download_result, $template, $torrent
```

From what I can tell, $template is never defined.